# Modo seguro de trabalhar com cookies

Tags: php

Colegas

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema do qual pretendo armazenar em um cookie o produto que ele selecionou, para caso ele feche o navegador e volte, o produto continue ativo dessa forma:

```
setcookie('compras',$_SESSION['produto'],time()+3600);
```

Porém estou preocupado se o cookie estiver desabilitado no navegador dele. Existe algum meio de resolver isso? Ou seja, ele selecionar um produto e não finalizar a compra, fechar o navegador e quando voltar, o produto ainda constar no carrinho dele.

Comment: Não sei se te vai ajudar, mas podes usar o [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Se os cookies estiverem desligados nem sequer a sessão funcionará, uma vez que o identificador da sessão exige o cookie, *ao menos que ignore o minimo de segurança passe o `id`da sessão por parâmetro de URL*. Você tem o LocalStore e também o WebSQL disponíveis em alguns navegadores. Porém se a pessoa esta com os cookies desligados ela estará com todo o resto também.

Comment: Nada impede você de emitir uma mensagem, pedindo para ativar os cookies, ora :p

Answer (score 1):

Verifique você mesmo se os cookies estão habilitados para o cliente. Se não estiverem, avise-o sobre as perdas de funcionalidade e peça-o para habilitar os cookies no navegador.

Você pode testar com PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();

setcookie('compras', $_SESSION['produto'],time()+3600);

header('Location: VerificaCookies.php');
```

Então, na página *VerificaCookies.php*:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['compras'])){
    echo 'Cookies habilitados';
} else {
    // Melhore as mensagens. Estas são só de exemplo
    echo 'Cookies desabilitados';
}
```

**EDIT 1:** DE ACORDO (QUASE) COM O COMENTÁRIO DO ANDERSON

Existe ainda a possibilidade de usar JavaScript - site da [**W3C**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_cookieenabled.asp) (não consegui verificar com Modernizr, porque há sites bloqueados para mim):

```
if(navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    cookies = true;
} else {
    cookies = false
}
```

Tem esse outro site, [**JavaScript Kit**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/cookiedetect.shtml) com exemplo mais completo também:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false

//if not IE4+ nor NS6+
if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined" && !cookieEnabled){ 
    document.cookie="testcookie"
    cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1)? true : false
}

//if (cookieEnabled) //if cookies are enabled on client's browser
//do whatever

</script>
```

Comment: Acredito que a mesma operação pode ser feita, também, com JavaScript, tal como a biblioteca [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) faz.